# How to sort rows with duplicated id's by specific value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I made a select with joins from DB table and as a result I have records with duplicated IDs. For ranking records (pagination purposes) I use dense_rank() over () in PostgreSQL. 
The question is: how can I order results by specific column value and its appropriate value from another column?

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT crm_leads.id,
          f.name,
          fv.value,
          dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY crm_leads.id) AS offset_
   FROM crm_leads
   INNER JOIN crm_modules AS m ON crm_leads.module_id = m.id
   INNER JOIN crm_fields AS f ON f.module_id = m.id
   LEFT JOIN crm_field_values AS fv ON fv.lead_id = crm_leads.id
   AND fv.field_id = f.id
   LEFT JOIN crm_field_type_values AS ftv ON ftv.field_id = f.id
   WHERE crm_leads.domain_uuid = '6191af69-9cb5-44f7-b455-3eae6f81d01d'
   AND m.id = 41 ) 
   AS result_offset
```

What I have after select:

```
| ID | NAME  | VALUE |
| 3  | name1 | 13    |
| 3  | name2 | 23    |
| 3  | name3 | 44    |
| 4  | name2 | 55    |
| 4  | name1 | 12    |
| 5  | name2 | 89    |
| 5  | name1 | 14    |
```

For example, I want to order by NAME: name1 value and its appropriate value. What I expect after sorting (values: 12, 13, 14):

```
| ID | NAME  | VALUE |
| 4  | name2 | 55    |
| 4  | name1 | 12    |
| 3  | name1 | 13    |
| 3  | name2 | 23    |
| 3  | name3 | 44    |
| 5  | name2 | 89    |
| 5  | name1 | 14    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the order by.  So I think you want an `order by` on the outer query:

```
order by min(value) over (partition by id), id
```

Note that you do not have an `order by` in the outermost query.  Hence, you are not guaranteed that the results will be in any particular order.  `order by` in subqueries does not guarantee ordering in the outer query.